# Can I make leiningen use a specific javac version?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Our build server has multiple versions of Java, to support our legacy projects that haven't yet updated to Java 1.8.

`javac -version` returns 1.7, which is what leiningen picks up (from /usr/bin/javac).

Is there a way to tell leiningen to use a different version of javac?

eg. we have 1.8 installed at `/home/ubuntu/jdk1.8.0_11/bin/javac`

Answer (score 0):

Ghetto solution I came up with:

`PATH=/home/ubuntu/jdk1.8.0_11/bin/:$PATH lein dist`

I'm hoping there's an alternative approach.